# Custom navigation bar in android

Tags: android-custom-view

I want to make a navigation in android, just like the one in google play store, in which when you browse horizontally, you browse through tags like "top new free", "top new paid" "home" and etc.. 
can anyone help! A.S.A.P

Comment: Please, show some code or an effort to a research

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a custom view, check out [this example](https://labs.ribot.co.uk/exploring-the-new-android-design-support-library-b7cda56d2c32?gi=20711dc35bff)!

Comment: thanx man.. im really a beginner.. just started working on android. that was really helpful.. I didnt even know where to begin.. :) thanx..